# The Python instance can not be converted to a COM object while trying to move an Outlook email

Tags: python, winapi, outlook

Sorry, but days of surfing even the darkest waters around haven´t provided an answer.

I can read the emails, and I can create new folders, but when I try to mark them as read, or when I try to move them to another folder, I get this "Python instance can not be converted to a COM object".

I´m now wondering if this might have to do with some security settings of Outlook.

Here´s the code:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.inbox = self.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(6)
    self.MyFolder = self.inbox.Folders['TESTING']
    messages = self.MyFolder.Items
    for message in messages:
        if message.UnRead:
                try:
                    Found = False
                    for x in self.MyFolder.Folders:
                        if x.Name == Alarm.group(1):
                            Found = True
                            message.Move(Alarm.group(1))
                            break
                except Exception as error:
                    print("Error: ", error)
                if not Found:
                    print("NOT FOUND")
                    self.MyFolder.Folders.Add(Alarm.group(1))
                    message.Move(Alarm.group(1))
            except AttributeError as ex:
                print('Error: ', ex, 'message not processed', message)
```

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Python is likely the worst possible programming environment to interop with COM. Have all your threads that use COM been initialized into the correct apartment? Do your STA threads dispatch messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MailItem.Move` takes an instance of the `MAPIFolder` OOM object as an argument. You are passing some Python object. A folder can be retrieved in a way similar to the way you retrieve `self.MyFolder`

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry, you are correct.  Changing the code this way:      for x in self.MyFolder.Folders:
       if x.Name == Alarm.group(1):
        Found = True
        print("FOUND") 
        message.Move(x)
        break                                                                            fixes the problem, and the emails are sent to their correct folders.